# Chess game multiple JPanels

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, grid-layout, chess

I have been trying to create a chess board using swing `JPanels` and `GridLayout` for each panel as shown in the picture.

Yellow is where the dead pieces will go and the red is the main board

[image]

I'm trying to get 3 grid layout on each panel; how can I get them to look like in the picture?

Comment: The questions is to general. Try to elaborate more on what you have already tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

You have your choice of layouts to use. You could use a FlowLayout, BoxLayout, GridBagLayout or even a BorderLayout.

The key when using layout managers is that you can nest panels with different layout manager to get your desired effect. Read the tutorial, download the examples and experiment.